# Ajax Delete give 405 (Method Not Allowed) in laravel 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Don't understand why have to error in the method. What I do wrong?
 I'm using Ziggy routing for js

```
management.site.destroy:
domain: null
methods: ["DELETE"]
uri: "management/site/{id}"
```

Have console error

`DELETE http://localhost/blog/public/management/site 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

have button and js on it

```
<button type="button" name="ok_button" id="ok_button" class="btn btn-danger">OK</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click', '#ok_button', (function (e) {
    var product_id = $(this).val();
    var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
    $.ajax({
        url: route('management.site.destroy',product_id),
        beforeSend:function(){
            $('#ok_button').text('Deleting...');
        },
        type: 'delete',
        data: {'product_id':product_id,
            '_token': token,},
        success: function (data) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');
                    alert('Data Deleted');
                    location.reload();
                }, 2000);
        }
    });
}));
```

Controller:

```
    public function destroy($id)
    {

        $company_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $item = Site::firstWhere(['company_id'=>$company_id,'id'=>$id]);
    $item->delete();
    return response()->json(['success' => 'Data is successfully Deleted']);
    }
```

Route  (Edited added full route) in patch and etc work fine

```
Route::group([ 'as'=>'management.','namespace' => 'Management', 'prefix' => 'management','middleware' => ['role:administrator'] ], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'ManagementController@index');
    Route::group(['as' => 'site.','prefix' => 'site'], function () {
        Route::get('/','SiteController@index')->name('index');
        Route::post('store','SiteController@store')->name('store');
        Route::post('edit/{id}','SiteController@edit')->name('edit');
        Route::get('edit/{id}','SiteController@edit')->name('edit');
        Route::patch('','SiteController@update')->name('update');
        Route::delete('{id}','SiteController@destroy')->name('destroy');
        Route::get('{id}','SiteController@view')->name('view');
    });
```

Comment: You have to add a data property named `_method` with value `'delete'` to your ajax call, and `type:` should be 'post'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this:

```
Route::delete('{id}','SiteController@destroy')
```

wrapped in a `Route` group?

If it is not, then your `delete()` methods route will actually be `/{id}` and not `management/site/{id}`

---

In your console, run `php artisan route:list` to display the full list of registered routes for your application. Then check what the registered route is for your delete method.

---

**Edit (Round 2)**

So the registered route is:

```
| DELETE | management/site/{id} | management.site.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\Management\SiteController@destroy | web,role:administrator
```

This is expecting the delete request to be `http://localhost/management/site/{id}`

However, the error being returned indicates the path the request is making is incorrect:

```
DELETE http://localhost/blog/public/management/site 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

It may well be that you have a relative path somewhere which is adding the `/blog/public/` section of your URI!

**TLDR;**

`http://localhost/blog/public/management/site` != `http://localhost/management/site/{id}`

Comment: Can you provide the relevant entry from the `php artisan route:list` command?

Comment: in my route list it look like this 
`| DELETE    | management/site/{id}                   | management.site.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\Management\SiteController@destroy                 | web,role:administrator`

Comment: Updated my answer as it explains the error. The exact cause still eludes me right now

Comment: Thanks, yeah problem was at routes